# Adding to a dataframe a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Start_Time
2016-02-08 05:46:00
2016-02-08 06:07:59
2016-02-08 06:49:27
2016-02-08 07:23:34
```

This is a column of a dataframe I am working with. How can I add to the dataframe an extra column that holds the day of the week that the `Start_Time` occurred in each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your column is already a datetime we can use the `dt.` accessor to use datetime methods

if not use `pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'])`

```
df['day_name'] = df['Start_Time'].dt.day_name()
```

or

```
df['dayofweek'] = df['Start_Time'].dt.dayofweek
```

---

```
           Start_Time day_name  dayofweek
0 2016-02-08 05:46:00   Monday          0
1 2016-02-08 06:07:59   Monday          0
2 2016-02-08 06:49:27   Monday          0
3 2016-02-08 07:23:34   Monday          0
```